# Achieving break pages with jsPDF / html2canvas and the .html method

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, page-break

I am using the latest jsPDF (2.1.1), html2canvas (v1.0.0-rc.7) and the .html method. I tried to achieve a page break by adding the following CSS style on a DIV
page-break-before: always
but without success.

My search resulted on conflicting information on whether the above should work.
Any help will be great!

Comment: Are you getting any errors you can share with the community?

Comment: @plushyObject 2   No errors, the style "page-break-before: always" seems to have no effect (there is no page break).